# Why doesn't i get input as a string for program below

Tags: java

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
//prompt the user input for a number
int a  = keyboard.nextInt();
//prompt the user input for a string
String str = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Get Input for String

Comment: There is likely still a new line character in the input stream after `nextInt`, which means it's just skipping straight over the `nextLine`

Answer (score 0):

The `.nextLine()` is getting the '\n' character trailing the integer. Fix this by adding `keyboard.nextLine()` after the `.nextInt()`. As follows:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
// prompt the user input for a number
int a  = keyboard.nextInt();
// prompt the user input for a string
keyboard.nextLine(); // This captures the '\n' character trailing the integer
String str = keyboard.nextLine();
```